# Equal width spacing with div table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out why I keep having first column in my div table have more space than the rest of the columns.  I don't understand what is so special about it considering I apply the same CSS to all columns equally.  I am trying to keep the same equal width for all columns.  But look what I have:

[image: Why is space between Value1 and Value2 greater than space between Value 2 and Value 3?]

My goal is to have the same equal space between Value1, Value 2, Value3 and Value 4.  Here is my CSS and its HTML:

```
.Table2
{
    display: table;
    background:white;
}

.Row2
{
    display: table-row;
}


.Cell3
{
    display: table-cell;
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}


.Cell4
{
    display: table-cell;
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    border-top:1px solid;
}

.Cell5
{
    display: table-cell;
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    border-bottom:1px solid;
}
```

I did the research and this is how div tables are made.  According to examples I've seen, they all had the same equal spacing, but why am I having one column with greater space than the rest?  I don't understand what is so special about Value 1 column in my CSS  This is my HTML:

```
<div class="Table2">
   <div class="Row2">
      <div class="Cell3">
         <p><font class="textlargedarkblue"> Info: </font> <font class="textTotalPrice1"> $1.00</font></p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="Row2">
      <div class="Cell4">
        <p><font class="textsmalldarkblue"> Value1 </font></p>
      </div>
      <div class="Cell4">
        <p><font class="textsmall"> Value2 </font></p>
      </div>
      <div class="Cell4">
        <p><font class="textsmall"> Value3 </font></p>
      </div>
      <div class="Cell4">
        <p><font class="textlittle">Value4 </font></p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Could somebody explain to me how I can keep all Value columns have the same space width?

P.S. The CSS for Value1 is not having any spacing of its own, it's simply defining font and color:

```
.textlargedarkblue{font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-size:16px; color:darkblue; font-weight: bold}
```

Same for Value2..Value4 So that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Offtopic: why not use a `<table>`, to display *tabular* content???

Comment: You have only one cell in your first table row – and the second cell in the second row is made exactly the same width, because that is how tables are _supposed_ to work. If you want to display only one value in the first row and don’t want to have that effect – then make that row not be part of the table in the first place (by removing `.Row2 { display: table-row; }`)

Comment: OMG!  Thank you CBroe!  The first row was the culprit and I totally forgot about it!  When I remove it everything became evenly spaced so it definitely had effect and now I know the problem to work on. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That column is stretching to fit your `Info: $1.00` line. You should put that in a div or something separate, since it isn't part of the table. Or make that row a different class and remove the `display: table-row;` for it.

Answer (score -1):

My honest opinion is that you should use table's for this matter... they're created to display tabular content.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="4">Info: <span>$1.00</span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Value 1</td>
        <td>Value 2</td>
        <td>Value 3</td>
        <td>Value 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    border: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table th {
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
table td {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/uy8gmge0/).

Comment: Thank you so much for your advise!  Yes, I originally had it all implemented using tables and had no problems, unfortunately, this is for mobile device view and according to what I read divs are more efficient than tables as somebody mentioned they require less code.  I have a very large set of data and really need to "squish" as much code as possible :)  Thanks again.

Comment: How is your code less?? You have a `div` instead of the `table`, a `div` instead of the `tr`, and a `div` instead of a `td`... same amount of elements.... I do agree that in some cases, when talking responsive designing, div are more flexible. But it totally depends on what data you want to show, and how you want to show it.

Comment: Stick to answering the question.  If you want to suggest they change their markup to something else, use comments.  Based on the information presented, I have no reason to believe that this is tabular data.